# ValueError: This function does not handle missing values

Tags: python, valueerror

```
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(Train['Count'],period=30).plot)
result = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(train.Count) 
plt.show()
```

> help me to solve this error!!
>
> i tried this in an ml based traffic project but its not working and
> showing value error

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-70db076f167d> in <module>
----> 1 decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(Train['Count'], period =30).plot()
      2 result = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(train.Count)
      3 plt.show()

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, period, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
    130 
    131     if not np.all(np.isfinite(x)):
--> 132         raise ValueError("This function does not handle missing values")
    133     if model.startswith('m'):
    134         if np.any(x <= 0):

ValueError: This function does not handle missing values
```

Answer (score 4):

In [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) says about the `isfinite` function:

> Test element-wise for finiteness (not infinity and not Not a Number). The result is returned as a boolean array.

Let's try to check result for our df:

```
import numpy as np
np.isfinite(df['value'])
```

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | True |
| 3 | True |
| 4 | True |

One of values returns False, we can find it:

```
df[df.index.isin(np.isfinite(df[['value']]).query('not value').index)]
```

And we can fill empty values:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(0)
```

Now, it will work:

```
seasonal_decompose(df['value'])
```